# Get a StackPane's width

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I can't figure out how to get a StackPane's width :

If i refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html, a StackPane's dimensions should adapt to it's content :

> A stackpane's parent will resize the stackpane within the stackpane's resizable range during
> layout. By default the stackpane computes this range based on its content as outlined in the
> table below.
>
> preferredWidth    left/right insets plus the largest of the children's pref widths.

Syntax here is scala, but the issue concerns javafx :

```
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle

class Bubble() extends StackPane {
val rect = new Rectangle(100, 100)

getChildren.add(rect)

println(rect.getWidth)
println(this.getWidth)
}

Output :
>> 100.0
>> 0.0 <- Why isn't it 100 ?
```

Is this a bug or the awaited behaviour ? How can i get a StackPane's content width ?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout managers (and actually all resizable objects) don't update their bounds until application being actually shown. Rectangle gives width 100 because it's default value with your constructor.

See next code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    root.getChildren().add(rect);

    // 100 - 0
    System.out.println(rect.getWidth());
    System.out.println(root.getWidth());

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    // 100 - 0
    System.out.println(rect.getWidth());
    System.out.println(root.getWidth());

    stage.show();

    // 100 - 100
    System.out.println(rect.getWidth());
    System.out.println(root.getWidth());
}
```

So you need either wait StackPane to be shown. Or better rely on JavaFX on that matter and use binding. E.g.

```
    stage.titleProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().asString());
```